# Database reference or recreation?

Tags: android, database, memory, performance

I have a quick performance question: Is it quicker and efficient on memory to use a static singleton database reference or reopen it every time you need to access something?

Thanks for any help,

~Aedon

Comment: Depends on the intensity of database access. Have you profiled your typical usage scenario?

Comment: I should have 1-10 accesses every minute or so. Granted this can go up to maybe 30. But that should be rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android the databases aren't kept in memory so keeping the reference will be light on your memory, but will use some file locks. Using a singleton would be my first choice, however, if you're using it in a service or a single activity, it doesn't necessarily need to be static. 
If you're database instance keeps a reference to a Context, then by all means avoid making it static because it will be a good source of memory leaks.